# Running React project is returning error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'public'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, yarnpkg

Error when trying to run project https://github.com.mcas.ms/floriankammermann/landscapeapp locally on my windows machine.

I am attempting to run the project from this repo:
https://github.com.mcas.ms/floriankammermann/landscapeapp

I cloned the project and installed the dependencies and now trying to run the project using 'yarn run open:src' I am getting the following error:

```
yarn dev
$ yarn yaml2json && yarn prepare-landscape && NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev
$ babel-node tools/generateJson.js
processed C:/Users/Adia-May/Git_repos/landscapes/cdf-landscape
$ babel-node tools/prepareLandscape.js
node:internal/fs/utils:347
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'public'
    at Object.lstatSync (node:fs:1574:3)
    at __node_internal_ (node:internal/fs/utils:803:8)
    at rmdirSync (node:fs:1215:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Adia-May\Git_repos\landscapes\landscapeapp\tools\/prepareLandscape.js:13:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:14)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\Adia-May\Git_repos\landscapes\landscapeapp\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:136:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\Users\Adia-May\Git_repos\landscapes\landscapeapp\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:141:7)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:930:12) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'lstat',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'public'
}

Node.js v18.14.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

'public' doesnt seem to be a file in the project
Here is the scripts from the package.json file:

```
 "scripts": {
    "autocrop-images": "babel-node tools/autocropImages",
    "dev": "yarn yaml2json && yarn prepare-landscape && NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev",
    "open:src": "yarn dev",
    "open:dist": "yarn stop-old-ci && babel-node tools/distServer.js",
    "get-iframe-resizer-path": "node -e \"console.info(require.resolve('iframe-resizer/js/iframeResizer.min.js'))\" ",
    "landscapes": "babel-node tools/landscapes.js",
    "lint": "esw webpack.config.* src tools --color",
    "lint:watch": "yarn lint -- --watch",
    "update-github-colors": "curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Diastro/github-colors/master/github-colors.json > tools/githubColors.json",
    "migrate": "babel-node tools/migrate",
    "fetch": "babel-node tools/validateLandscape && yarn migrate && babel-node tools/checkWrongCharactersInFilenames && babel-node tools/addExternalInfo.js && yarn yaml2json",
    "fetchAll": "LEVEL=complete yarn fetch",
    "update": "(rm /tmp/landscape.json || true) && babel-node tools/validateLandscape && yarn migrate && yarn remove-quotes && LEVEL=medium babel-node tools/addExternalInfo.js && yarn prune && yarn check-links && yarn yaml2json && babel-node tools/calculateNumberOfTweets && babel-node tools/updateTimestamps",
    "yaml2json": "babel-node tools/generateJson.js",
    "remove-quotes": "babel-node tools/removeQuotes",
    "prune": "babel-node tools/pruneExtraEntries",
    "check-links": "babel-node tools/checkLinks",
    "remove-dist": "rimraf \"$PROJECT_PATH\"/dist",
    "precommit": "yarn fetch",
    "host-images": "babel-node tools/hostImages.js && yarn fetch",
    "start-ci": "yarn exec bash -c \"(yarn run babel-node tools/distServer.js &) && sleep 10\"",
    "stop-old-ci": "yarn run babel-node tools/stopOldDistServer.js",
    "stop-ci": "yarn exec bash -c \"kill -9 `cat /tmp/ci.pid` >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && rm /tmp/ci.pid \"",
    "integration-test": "jest ${JEST_OPTIONS:-} --reporters=./tools/jestReporter.js --reporters=jest-standard-reporter",
    "check-landscape": "babel-node tools/checkLandscape",
    "render-landscape": "babel-node tools/renderLandscape",
    "funding": "babel-node tools/fundingForMasterBranch",
    "copy-dist": "cp -r _headers out && ([ -z \"${PROJECT_NAME:-}\" ] || mkdir \"$PROJECT_PATH\"/dist ) && cp -r out/ \"$PROJECT_PATH\"/dist/${PROJECT_NAME:-}",
    "prepare-landscape": "babel-node tools/prepareLandscape.js",
    "setup-robots": "babel-node tools/sitemap && babel-node tools/addRobots",
    "quick-build": "yarn build-next && yarn setup-robots && yarn copy-dist ",
    "build": "((yarn fetch && yarn prepare-landscape && yarn build-next && yarn setup-robots && yarn remove-dist && yarn copy-dist && yarn stop-old-ci && yarn start-ci && babel-node tools/parallelWithRetry integration-test check-landscape render-landscape funding) || (yarn stop-old-ci && false)) && babel-node tools/parallelWithRetry integration-test && yarn stop-ci",
    "build-custom": "yarn fetch && yarn prepare-landscape && yarn build-next && yarn setup-robots && yarn remove-dist && yarn copy-dist",
    "build-next": "next build && next export",
    "show-report": "open dist/report.html",
    "analyze-bundle": "babel-node ./tools/analyzeBundle.js",
    "latest": "yarn",
    "reset-tweet-count": "babel-node tools/resetTweetCount.js",
    "prepublish": "cp yarn.lock _yarn.lock",
    "postpublish": "rm _yarn.lock || true"
  }
```

What does this mean? I am a complete novice in react and yarn and have been trying to fix the error for a week or so. Is it a runtime error or a problem with my installation? I can upload any files needed

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may need to run `yarn build`. What is creating the `public` folder? Do a search for `public` in your entire code-base.

Comment: I found out the answer, it was an issue with dependencies when the yarn install happened.

Answer (score 0):

I found out my issue, I had dependency issues after calling `yarn` to download dependencies.